# How to create a list with links to available django-forms-builder forms

Tags: django, forms

I came across django-forms-builder today and trying it out in a project. Ive got it installed and can create forms within the admin area, which is great! But I am struggling to figure out how to use it in my templates. I want a page of links to the forms thats separate from the admin area and also create the links for new forms that are made so no one has to edit the html links every time someone creates a new form.

Comment: I'd rephrase the title of your question: "How to create a list with links to available django-forms-builder forms"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms builder user here!

`django-forms-builder` forms are just objects of class [`forms.models.Form`](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder/blob/master/forms_builder/forms/models.py#L256). You can list them in a normal view.

To use these `Form` instances you need to feed them to [`FormFormForm`](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder/blob/master/forms_builder/forms/forms.py#L117) like this:

```
FormForForm(form, RequestContext(request),
                                request.POST or None,
                                request.FILES or None)
```

and then use it in your post view. See [this view](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder/blob/master/forms_builder/forms/views.py#L41).

To display them you can simply use the `render_built_form` template tag:

```
{% render_built_form form_instance %}
```

See [Usage](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder#usage).